# Variable font sizes in Java Swing

Tags: java

I'm looking for a way to create fonts in Swing components such as JLabel and JTextField that can be scaled in non integer sizes.  Testing using a JLabel shows font sizes only display in point sizes that are integers.
Here is test code showing what happens with different font sizes.

```
package test;

import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class TestFontSize
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater (new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                showFrame();
            }
        });
    }

    private static void showFrame()
    {
        JFrame fontTestFrame = new JFrame();
        int iFrameLeft = 50;
        int iFrameTop = 20;         
        int iFrameWidth = 900;
        int iFrameHeight = 560;
        int iLabelWidth = iFrameWidth - iFrameLeft*2;
        fontTestFrame.setBounds(iFrameLeft, iFrameTop, iFrameWidth, iFrameHeight);
        fontTestFrame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter()
        {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e)
            {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        Container con = fontTestFrame.getContentPane();
        con.setLayout(null);

        Font lblBaseFont = new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 16);
        int iLabelHeight = 22;
        float fInitialFontSize = 12;
        float fFontSizeIncrement = (float)0.09;
        int iInitialTopPosition = 10;
        int iNumLoops = (iFrameHeight-(25 + iInitialTopPosition*2))/(iLabelHeight+2);
        System.out.println("iNumLoops: " + iNumLoops);

        for (int i=0; i<iNumLoops; i++)
        {
            float fNewFontSize = (float)(fInitialFontSize + i*fFontSizeIncrement);
            int iVerticalPosition = iInitialTopPosition + i*(iLabelHeight+2);
            Font lblNewFont = lblBaseFont.deriveFont(fNewFontSize);
            JLabel lbl = new JLabel("The swift fox jumped over the lazy brown dog - Font sie: " + fNewFontSize);
            lbl.setFont(lblNewFont);
            lbl.setBounds(20, iVerticalPosition, iLabelWidth, iLabelHeight);
            con.add(lbl);
        }
        fontTestFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

If you run this, you'll see that font sizes don't scale in line with size, but jump from one size to the next.
I've tried using imported true type fonts, affinetransform version of derivedFont and html code in the JLabel to specify the font size.  No joy.

Is it possible?

Comment: Possible (at all)? Yes. Possible with pure Java? I'm not sure. Easy? Probably not much. How to do it? No idea...

Comment: Fonts are always difficult. Imagine a string like `xxxxx` which may be exactly 25 pixels wide with font size 5, and 20 pixels with font size 4. When you paint it with font size 4.9, then one of the `x`es basically *will* have to look different than the others - and it will look odd. One possibility could be to paint into a custom `Graphics`, with `RenderingHints.KEY_FRACTIONALMETRICS` and anti-aliasing enabled, but I'm not sure whether this would work so nicely (and it would be fiddly in any case). Maybe the usual Swing experts here have an idea.